# Как определить из кода программы (на с++) текущее состояние исправности питания компьютера (сигнала Power Good)?

Tags: c++, c

В Windows. Собственно, дополнить больше нечего, разве что зачем - чтобы программа останавливала обработку данных.

Comment: ЕМНИП, если сигнал пропадает, то компьютер немедленно уходит в перезагрузку, так что преостановить обработку данных не удастся, а с здачей вполне справится `bool isPowerGood() {return true;}`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, не совсем так просто — сигнал обрабатывается микроконтроллером (и даже не одним), хотя для пользователя выглядит примерно как вы описали. Кстати, вопрос мог быть вполне про код самой прошивки одного из таких микроконтроллеров.

Comment: @0andriy, пока, говорят, не придумали контроллеров, работающих на win... про остальное — я не уверен — я бы просто подвесил на него инвертор, который выдаёт сигнал reset при отсутствии PG... есть какая-нить типовая схема, как он разведён? или пруф, что он заходит хотя бы в один из мостов?... ну и для плат интел я, конечно, добавил бы его на вход шпионского чипа для «всеобщего удобства»...